# Limits and exponents and e exponent form

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

So I know that $\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\text{lim}}\left(1+\frac {1}{n}\right)^n=e$ 
and that we're not allowed to see it as $1^\infty$ because that'd be incorrect. 
Why is then that we can do the same thing with (for example): $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(1+\sin\left(\frac {1}{n}\right)\right)^{n\cos\left(\frac {1}{n}\right)}= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(\left(1+\sin\left(\frac {1}{n}\right)\right)^\frac {1}{\sin\left(\frac {1}{n}\right)} \right)^{n\cdot\cos\left(\frac {1}{n}\right)\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}$$

What I mean by that is that in the example of $e$ we can't say it'  $\lim \left(1+\frac {1}{n}\right)^{\lim  (n)}=1^\infty$

While in the second example that's exactly what we do (we say that the limit of the base is $e$ while the limit of the exponent is 1 which is why the entire expression is equal to $e$.

Can anyone explain to me the difference between the two?

Answer (score 3):

In fact there's no difference between the two examples, indeed if you have a function $h$ such that $h(n)\to\infty$ then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{h(n)}\right)^{h(n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}=e$$
and ofcourse if we have another function $f$ such that $f(n)\to a\in\mathbb R$ then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{h(n)}\right)^{h(n)}\right)^{f(n)}=e^a.$$

Comment: Well said! ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 3):

This might give you an idea about how you can generalize the limit

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = e.
$$

Suppose $a_n \to 0$ and $b_n \to \infty$.  Then

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+a_n)^{b_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \exp\Bigl[b_n \log(1+a_n)\Bigr] = C
$$

if and only if

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n \log(1+a_n) = \log C.
$$

Now

$$
b_n \log(1+a_n) = a_n b_n \frac{\log(1+a_n)}{a_n},
$$

and since

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\log(1+x)}{x} = 1
$$

We may conclude that

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+a_n)^{b_n} = C
$$

if and only if

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n b_n = \log C.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The expression $1^\infty$ is an **indeterminate** expression, i.e. one of those guys that you should get alarmed about when they appear as limit expression if one naively replaces $\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n\circ b_n)$ with $(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n)\circ (\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n)$. Doing so is only justified where the binary operation $\circ$ is both defined and continuous. You may know that $\frac00$, $\frac\infty\infty$, $0\cdot\infty$ and $\infty-\infty$ are indeterminate, but so is $1^\infty$ and also $0^0$. Note that the notion of **indeterminate** expression is to be distinguished from **undefined** expression (though things like $\frac00$ happen to be also undefined). Right here however, we have to deal with the fact that $(x,y)\mapsto x^y$ is not continuous at $(x,y)=(1,\infty)$ (and also not at $(x,y)=(0,0)$). Therefore, if $a_n\to 1$ and $b_n\to \infty$, virtually anything can happen with $a_n^{b_n}$.

This is so in spite of the fact that it does make perfect sense algebraically to say that $1^\infty=1$ (and also $0^0=1$) if one takes $a^b$ as the number of maps from a $b$-element set to an $a$-element set. However, the only nice way to define exponentiation analytically is via logarithm and exponentaila, i.e. $x^y:=\exp(y\ln x)$. In this light, the indeterminacy of $1^\infty$ and $0^0$ corresponds to the "well-known" indeterminacy of $\infty\cdot 0$ or $0\cdot\infty$.

Comment: So pretty much what you're saying that it's indeterminate because it's the base is 1. If it were any other number we determine the limit like in the second example?

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)^{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)^{\lim_{x\to a}g(x)}\iff $ both $\lim_{x\to a}f(x), \lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ exists.

While in first case $\lim_{n\to \infty}n$ doesn't exist, but in second case, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\sin\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{\sin\frac{1}{n}}}=e$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}n\cos\frac{1}{n}\sin\frac{1}{n}=1$ both exist.

Comment: And what would you have said if the exponent's limit was infinity and the base was a finite number that isn't one? based on what would you say the limit is equal to $\infty$

Comment: In that case, definition doesn't apply as limit equal to $\infty$ is not taken as limit exists

Comment: So how would you justify that the limit is infinity in that case?