# Conclusion about limit definition of e^a for a sequence of real numbers {a_n} converging to a?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, limits, exponential-function

I have seen this fact used in several demonstrations, but have never seen a proof of it.

I believe the statement is: If $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of real numbers such that $a_n \rightarrow a$ finite, then $(1 + \frac{a_n}{n} )^n \rightarrow e^a $.

Any help or references appreciated!

Comment: One way to show this is with the method described in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/436140/5531).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach starts from the fact that $\mathrm e^{x-x^2}\leqslant1+x\leqslant\mathrm e^x$ for every $x\geqslant-\frac12$ and that $\frac{a_n}n\geqslant-\frac12$ for every $n$ large enough, hence, applying this to $x=\frac{a_n}n$ for every $n$ such that $\frac{a_n}n\geqslant-\frac12$ yields
$$
\mathrm e^{nx-nx^2}\leqslant\left(1+\frac{a_n}n\right)^n\leqslant\mathrm e^{nx},
$$
that is,
$$
\mathrm e^{a_n-a_n^2/n}\leqslant\left(1+\frac{a_n}n\right)^n\leqslant\mathrm e^{a_n}.
$$
Since $a_n\to a$ and $\frac{a_n^2}n\to0$, the LHS and the RHS both converge to $\mathrm e^a$.

Answer (score 0):

No special estimation is needed.

It **is correct** to conclude that $f_n(a_n)$ converges to $f(a)$ in this case, because for large enough $n$ (in fact for $n  > |a|$), all the $f_n$ are monotonic on an interval containing $a$.  The principle is

> if $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for all $x$, the limit $f(x)$ is continuous at $a$, and there is a $\delta > 0$ such that all $f_n$ are monotonic on $(a - \delta, a+ \delta)$ for $n \geq n_0$, then $f_n(a_n) \to f(a)$ for any sequence $a_n$ converging to $a$.

For a proof, take $\epsilon$ a positive parameter tending to $0$, $n$ large enough so that $a_n$ is in a small subinterval $(a- \epsilon,a+\epsilon)$ of the interval of monotonicity, then $f_n(a_n)$ is bounded between the min and max of $(f_n(a - \epsilon), f_n(a+\epsilon))$ and so is asymptotically bounded between $f(a - \epsilon)$ and $f(a + \epsilon)$. This sandwich of upper and lower bounds converges to $f(a)$ for small $\epsilon$.

Continuity of $f_n(x)$ was not used, only continuity at $x=a$ of the limit $f(x)$.

Answer (score -2):

This is  called sequential continuity, one of the equivalent forms of continuity that applies to Real numbers , that says : $x_n\rightarrow x$ , then $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x) $ , i.e., if the sequence $x_n$ converges to $x$, then the sequence $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$. Note that there are spaces where continuity and sequential continuity are not equivalent. Can you tell how it applies here?

EDIT: More formally: if $a_n \rightarrow a$, we have,  $Lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (1+a_n/n)^n=e^{Lim_n\rightarrow \infty a_n}=e^a$

EDIT 2: The argument above is correct, but incomplete. I will include a justification
when I can make it rigorous, or delete if I cannot do so in a couple of days.

There is a straightforward argument for why $(1+a_n/n)^n=e^{Lim_n\rightarrow \infty a_n}=e^a$: basically, $a_n$ will converge to $a$, and then $a_n$ will become a constant, so that the situation reduces to that of $Lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1+x/n)^n=e^x$:

For given $\epsilon>0$ , we can find a positive integer $N$ with $|a_n-a|< \epsilon$ for all $n>N$ , and there is a positive integer $N'$ with $|(1+x/n)^n-e^x |<\epsilon$ for all $n>N'$. Now, choose $N_2>$ $Max${${N,N'}$}. Then $$(1+(a-\epsilon)/N_2)^{N_2} <(1+a/{N_2})^{N_2}< (1+(a+\epsilon)/N_2)^{N_2}$$ Now let $N_2$ become even larger, so that $\epsilon$ gets increasingly-closer to $0$, and the left- and right- sides of the inequality will squeeze the middle term into being $e^a$

Comment: This observation is not strong enough to solve this problem. Functions vary with $n$ (e.g. $f_n(x_n)$).

Comment: I see. So equivalently, we need to show $e^a_n \rightarrow e^a$, and since $f(x) = e^x$ is a continuous function, together with the hypothesis, we are done?

Comment: Right, if you show $a_n\rightarrow a$ , then, by continuity of $e^x$ , it follows that $e^{a_n}\rightarrow e^{a}$

Comment: @Lord Soth: I'm defining $e^x=Lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$ . Then , by continuity of $e^x$, if $x_n\rightarrow x$ , $e^{x_n}\rightarrow e^x$.

Comment: @user99680, but the question is about $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+a_n/n)^n$, not $\lim_{n_1 \to \infty} \lim_{n_2 \to \infty} (1+a_{n_1}/n_2)^{n_2}$.

Comment: @Antonio Vargas: But I'm using: $e^{a_n}\rightarrow e^a$ , by continuity of $e^x$. And $e^{a_n}:=Lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1+a_n/n)^n$

Comment: No.... it is **not** true that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+a_n/n)^n = e^{a_n}$.

Comment: Sorry, should be $Lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (1+a_n/n)=e^{Lim_n\rightarrow \infty a_n}=e^a$

Comment: It's the first equality there that requires justification.  It's true (except for the missing $n$ in the exponent), but you have not justified it.

Comment: Yes, I missed the n in the exponent. I will try to write a better justification for that step, but I need to go now; will edit again later.

Comment: O.K, I edited again and gave my justification for why $Lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1+a_n/n)^n=e^a$.

Comment: So, anyone still believe my argument is incorrect? Where so?

Comment: O.K, I deleted some posts; sorry I flew off the handle. Please explain the down-votes; I just want some input so I can learn.

Comment: Enjoy your punishing; I came here to learn, not to be scolded without reason.

Comment: I think people are jumping to hypercorrect an answer that is technically wrong but philosophically reasonable (addressing the "real" question of how to give a natural proof of the statement and not a chain of estimates specific to these $f_n$) and potentially fixable in an illuminating way (for example, by defining a space of functions and a topology on it, in which the needed convergence properties are apparent).

Comment: @zyx: could you please suggest a correction?

Comment: I posted an answer.  If i think of something more specific to your argument I will comment here.